# Why is this showing everytime I try to open Neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

When I start Neovim I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/dell/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/dell/.config/nvim/lua/core/bootstra
p.lua:33: module 'plugins' not found:
        no field package.preload['plugins']
        no file './plugins.lua'
        no file '/__w/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/luajit-2.1/plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/plugins/init.lua'
        no file '/__w/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/plugins.lua'
        no file '/__w/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/plugins/init.lua'   
        no file './plugins.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/plugins.so'
        no file '/__w/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/lib/lua/5.1/plugins.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/dell/.config/nvim/lua/core/bootstrap.lua:33: in function 'lazy'  
        /home/dell/.config/nvim/init.lua:16: in main chunk
```

What should I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you using a Neovim distribution (e.g. [NvChad](https://nvchad.com/))? If so can you tell us which one?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are using the [NvChad](https://nvchad.com/) distribution and that for some reason it is not correctly installed.

I suspect that you are missing the `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins` folder or the `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/init.lua` file in it.

Comment: Yes, I was i trying to install NvChad. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I suppose you have to reinstall it. You can do that be removing the `nvim` folder and redoing the installation.